# How to use a button's "data-" attribute to call a selected JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to set some data on my buttons such that it can be accessed `onclick`. I'm having no problem using JSON in a button's data attribute where the key value is a string. However, I can't figure out how to set the values to be a function.

What I'd like to happen upon clicking the button in this demo code is for the click event to call the function `option1()` which will alert the string "hello outside".

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'option1' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

HTML (JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/NDaEh/32/):

```
<button type='button' data-button='{"option1": "option1", "option2": 
"option2"}'>click1</button>
```

JS:

```
var data='hello outside';
var option1=function(data){
    alert(data)
}  

$('button').click(function(){
  //var data='hello inside';
  $(this).data('button').option1(data); // should alert 'hello outside'
});
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the following code to get the values in your HTML:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var data = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-button'));
  alert(data.option1)
});
```

This code is specifically for your requirement. By this way, you can store data in HTML and retrieve in JavaScript code.

Updated the JSFiddle code, working code is available at: http://jsfiddle.net/NDaEh/51/

EDIT:

**Solution to call a function dynamically: http://jsfiddle.net/NDaEh/70/**
HTML:

```
<button type='button' data-button='{"func": "func1"}'>click1</button>
<button type='button' data-button='{"func": "func2"}'>click2</button>
```

JS:

```
var myFuncs = {
  func1: function () { alert('Function 1'); },
  func2: function () { alert('Function 2'); },
};

$('button').click(function(){
  var data = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-button'));

  myFuncs[data.func]();
});
```

Comment: thanks @IvenMS but the key thing I want is that data.option1 is itself a function and not just a string. So writing data.option1(data) calls the alert function and not vice versa.

Comment: Try this:
`var alert_data='hello outside';

function option1 (data){
        alert(data)
    }         
$('button').click(function(){
  var data = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-button'));
  window[data.option1](alert_data);
});`

Comment: The idea is to run the function declared in your document with `window["function_name"](arguments);`. Please check....

Comment: I understand the concept but your code is not working, its giving same error of `option1` not being a function as I was first getting

Comment: Try this link: http://jsfiddle.net/NDaEh/66/ It is working. The concept is little different, but the same logic.

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for, can you put this jsfiddle in your answer, I'll accept it, thanks for pursuing this, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 7):

Dont save objects as JSON strings in the html tag property value. Use the data() method instead.

```
$('input[type="button"]').data({ option1: 'o1', option2: 'o2' });
```

Also, when youre writing this:

```
$(this).data('button').option1(data);
```

`option1` would need to be a plugin in order to be chained on to the data method (or any jquery method for that matter). You would need tomething like this:

```
jQuery.fn.option1 = function () {

   alert($(this).data('option1'));

   return this;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NDaEh/56/)

Comment: why can't i save objects as JSON strings? also i don't want to generate this data using JS b/c it will be highly variable across my app and i've already spent the time to generate it with server side code (logic is wired in my mysql database)

Comment: @timpeterson Well, html tags property values should be wrapped with double quotes. JSON strings should be as well. So I wouldnt recommend it. You would end up with either invalid html or json.

Comment: @timpeterson How are you fetching the data from the server? By ajax? Or are you just printing it directly in to the html? And what serverside language are you using?

Comment: I'm just printing the HTML. I don't want to do that and then write all these $('button').data() assignments across my entire app since there are many different buttons and many different assignments.

Comment: @timpeterson Ok, if you insist on sticking with inline string objects, you could use the code that i posted and format then using `var myObject = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-button'))`

Comment: ok thanks yes i see $.parseJSON but using `myObject.option1(data)` still isn't alerting "hello outside". would you mind adding what you think works to this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NDaEh/32/ ?

Comment: @timpeterson Sorry about the delay, i went for lunch. Check out the fiddle that i posted. Is this what you need?

Comment: yes that' s on the right track, I don't need to extend the jquery object, it could extend some smaller object using a similar syntax right?

Comment: @timpeterson If you want to write a custom jquery method (aka plugin), thats how its done (In other words, as long as you want to use your method directly on the jquery object). If you dont want to do that you could extract the data object and pass it to your regular function and handle it there.

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery `data` as shown below:

```
$('input[type=button]').data('button-data', { option1: 'option1', option2: 'option2});
```

Use:

```
$('input[type=button]').data('button-data');  //{ option1: 'option1', option2: 'option2}
```

In order to get the data from the element